# Unable to sort by position

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm new to Magento, so was playing with the API Magento 1.9.3, the sorting does seem not to work whether ASC or DESC, I was trying to sort it by position.

```
$ruleId = 4;    
$catalog_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                            ->load($ruleId)
                            ->getProductCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
```

I have added the position number in the category's product. Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `setOrder` to `addAttributeToSort` It works for me

```
$ruleId = 4;    
$catalog_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->load($ruleId)
                    ->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code.

```
$ruleId = 4;    
$catalog_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->load($ruleId)
                    ->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$catalog_category->getSelect()->order('cat_index_position',  'ASC');
foreach($catalog_category as $_product){
    echo $_product->getName()." <br> ";
}
```

Make sure you have your indexes up to date.